# How do I protect against ajax-spam in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, spam-prevention

Good day,

I would like to know how to protect my website from ajax-spam. I'm looking to limit any ajax action per
users. Let's say 8 ajax-actions per minute.

An example of an action would be: a button to add/remove a blog posts "as my favorites".

Unless I'm wrong, I believe the best way would be using `$_SESSION`'s variable and to avoid someone/a bot to clear
cookies to avoid my protection. I'm allowing ajax-functions only to logged-on users.

Using database would make my protection useless because it's the unwanted database's writes I'm trying to avoid.

I have to mention that I actually use **PHP** as server-language and **jQuery** to proceeds my ajax calls.

Thank you

**Edit:**

The sentense

> ... to protect my website ...

is confusing but it's not about cross-domain ajax.

**Edit 2011-04-20:**
I added a bounty of 50 to it.

Comment: Why don't I just keep changing the date to get more calls? Also, cookies don't work against most/all bots. I can use PHP's curl to get around your limitation easily if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Basically, you limit actions, 8 per minute, then refuse all actions. This could work, even if i'm not sure limiting your users on ajax calls is the best thing to do :) No one loves to be limited in time or number when using a website - i sure don't

Comment: @Kevin, I doubt you can change the date yourself : it's a session variable. Also, even with cURL, you must send the good sessionid that match a logged-on user so you can proceed any action.

Comment: My assumption was that this is some sort of API. If not, I'd have to agree with you, unless there was a reason for it (like being a game). In the case of a game though, I'd use some sort of database tracking to prevent back doors.

Comment: @Tsadiq, Let's say I have a page similar to this one, and I would like to block users from spamming the "Favorite" button (on/off).

Comment: @Cybrix, Session vars would make it a bit tougher, yes. You had said cookies, so I was running off of that assumption. So my next question is, how do you know the session isn't new vs. someone deleting the session cookie?

Comment: As another note, it might be more helpful if, instead of posting what you are doing, you post what you are trying to accomplish in full detail. This will help people understand your solution, find holes in it, and, perhaps, make suggestions. As it stands right now I don't think you will get worthwhile answers.

Comment: @Kevin, the session variable is kept in a cookie. And to answer your question, if the user flushes it's cookie/session he will be logged-off. To make a successfull spam, he must log back in and spam 8 more times.

Comment: A forced logoff doesn't stop automation, but maybe that doesn't matter to you. Please updated your question per my other comment so I can actually help instead of going back and forth.

Comment: @Kevin, good point. I'll update my question. But I also, wanted to know if I was heading the good way with my thoughts.

Comment: @Cybrix i am assuming you are attempt to protect against cross-domain ajax spam right?

Comment: @kjy112, nope. Same domain spam. I'm trying to find a way to disallow the users from ajax-spamming.

Comment: @Cybrix have you consider putting captcha?

Comment: @kjy112, putting a captcha before an ajax-call? Here, I will give you an example of what I'm trying to accomplish: Scroll up a little bit in this very page and look at the big favorite button. That button is backed by ajax. You may click on it and click again to undo. Every time you click there are an ajax-call made behind. I'm trying to disallow users from spam-clicking it so I dont make uselesses writes in database every time because it's simply just getting click-spammed. I am not looking for a javascript solution there.I want it to be blocked server-side (no databases actions taken)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're only allowing AJAX actions to logged in users, this is really simple to solve.

- Create a timestamp field for each account. You can do this in the database, or leverage Memcached, or alternatively use a flat file.
- Each time the user makes a request through your AJAX interface, add the current timestamp to your records, and:
- Check to make sure the last eight timestamps aren't *all* before one minute ago.

From there you can add additional magic, like tempbanning accounts that flagrantly violate the speed limit, or comparing the IPs of violators against blacklists of known spammers, et cetera.

Comment: +1 good solution. Let's wait a bit to see the other solutions but I doubt it will be much different.

Comment: @Cybrix, sure thing.  As an addendum, if you find that you're getting a lot of scurrilous AJAX requests that are being caught by the account-limited model, it'd pay off to make sure that none of the login-checking logic involves complicated database queries like joins or more than a couple queries overall.  Exposing too much database overhead to an easily-hammered process like the session check makes you vulnerable to a DDoS attack.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about specific ajax-spam to your site, or ajax-spam in general?

If the latter, you can use hashes to prevent auto-sending forms, i.e. write your `hash()` one-way function which takes string and makes sha1-checksum of it.

So that's how you use it:

```
// the page is a blog post #357
$id = 357;
$type = 'post';
$hash = hash($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$type.$id);
```

Put that hash in hidden field which is **not** within the comment form or even hidden div, somewhere at the bottom of the page, and name it "control_hash" or something. Attach it's value to the ajax-request on form submit. When the form is received by the script, make a new hash from `$_REQUEST` data (excluding existing `$control_hash`) and check if they match.

If the form was submitted by bot, it won't have `$control_hash`, so it won't pass.

Comment: >> *If the form was submitted by bot, it won't have $control_hash, so it won't pass.*

This is assuming that the bot is generic, and not tailored to the specific site.  This is not a safe assumption to make.

Comment: @Kerin “When you assume, you make an ass out of u and me.”

Comment: ...Yes, that's more or less what I said.  Also I have no idea how to un-great your comment, that was an accident.

Comment: Your hash check solves nothing and adds no security beyond the time-based restriction he asked for in the first place.

Comment: @Kerin “There are no accidents.” I've mentioned that I was talking about bots in general. If you're running a site that is likely to become a target of the specifically tailored bots, of course you are supposed to use much more complex security methods than just hash checks, and that's the subject to ask on [this site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your idea in principle is good. Some things to consider though:

- If you track the limits globally then you may run into the issue of a bot [DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)ing your server and preventing legitimate users from being able to use your "Favourite" button.
- If you track the requests based on their IP then someone could use a bot network (multiple IPs) to get around your blocking. Depending on your site and what your preference is, perhaps limit based on a [subnet of the IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).
- Install and use [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) to store and track the requests, particularly if you are going to be tracking based on the IP. This should be faster than using session variables (someone might correct me on this).

Comment: Q: What's the benefits of Memcache over APC for something like this? (if any)

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but I was suggesting Memcache purely for storing the values in memory, rather than writing them to session files. AFAIK APC does a similar thing, so use either.

Comment: I believe the most efficient way to limit the ajax is per user, not per functions.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was just curious why that was your goto extension in this case. I assume it's similar to me liking Windex over the Target brand.

Comment: @Kevin, Haha. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code of the web-site, you can rewrite some of the javascript code that actually performs AJAX-request. I.e. your pages can have a hidden counter field, that is incremented every time a user clicks the button. And also you can have a timefield hidden on the page, in order to rate the frequency of clicks.

The idea is that you don't even have to send anything to the server at all - just check it on the client side inside the script. Of course, that will not help against the bots adressing directly to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the result of such a spam. If you just want to avoid writing to your database, all these check could end up taking more ressources than actually writing to the database.

Does the end justify the means?

You also have to judge what's the probability of such a spam. Most bots are not very smart and will miserably fail when there's some logging involved.

Just my 2 cents, the other answers are perfectly valid to avoid spam.

Answer (score 0):

Buy more powerful hosting to be able serve requests, don't limit them.
8 requests per minute it's ridiculous.
Anyway, if requests are 'legal', you should find ways how to serve requests, not how to limit them. And if not 'legal' - then deny them without any 'time' limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session field with a global variable holding the time of last ajax request. Since you want to allow 8 requests, make it an array of size 8 and check for the time differences. If it increases, (important) it might not always be a bot. give the user a chance with captcha or something similar. (a math problem  maybe?)

once the captcha is validated, allow the next few posts etc..

But do make sure that you are checking for that particular session and user.

Kerin's answer is good, I just wanted to emphasize on captcha.

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to use a function in every function views can interact, also, it should be in global library so you can use it anywhere.

```
if(is_logged_in())
{
    // do you code here 
}
```

while is_logged in is defined as follows

```
function is_logged_in($activated = TRUE)
{
    return $this->ci->session->userdata('status') === ($activated ? STATUS_ACTIVATED : STATUS_NOT_ACTIVATED);
}
```

you should set the status session when user login successfully.

Comment: how will it help protect against spam mate? as the user can login and then pass the cookie to the spam script